# @PropertySource loads another properties file from another project

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Why is it that when I try to output the data from a property file the data that would display is wrong?

In my ChatApp project I have datasource-cfg.properties file:

```
# DataSource
ds.database-driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
ds.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample
ds.username=app
ds.password=app
```

And When I try to output it somewhere in my program the datas are wrong.
Here is my ApplicationContextConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.icomm.chatapp.*")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value="classpath:datasource-cfg.properties")
public class ApplicationContextConfig
{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env1s;

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource()
    {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource rb = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rb.setBasenames(new String[]
        {
            "messages/validator"
        });
        return rb;
    }

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env1s.getProperty("ds.database-driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env1s.getProperty("ds.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env1s.getProperty("ds.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env1s.getProperty("ds.password"));
        System.out.println("--------------Property File------------");
        System.out.println("" + env1s.getProperty("ds.database-driver"));
        System.out.println("" + env1s.getProperty("ds.url"));
        System.out.println("" + env1s.getProperty("ds.username"));
        System.out.println("" + env1s.getProperty("ds.password"));
        System.out.println("--------------Data Source------------");
        System.out.println("" + dataSource.getUrl());
        System.out.println("" + dataSource.getUsername());
        System.out.println("" + dataSource.getPassword());
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager getTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource)
    {
        DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

And the result is no the same with whats in datasource-cfg.properties file

```
Info:   Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Info:   --------------Property File------------
Info:   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Info:   jdbc:mysql://192.168.28.52:3306/retina
Info:   dbmail
Info:   dbmail
Info:   --------------Data Source------------
Info:   jdbc:mysql://192.168.28.52:3306/retina
Info:   dbmail
Info:   dbmail
```

I noticed that these data is from another project. In my SpringFrameworkApp. Can somebody help me with this. I want to access the datasource-cfg.properties in ChatApp Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per check, the datasource-cfg-properties that was accessed is indeed inside the Chat App but for some reason it is located under Other Sources > src/main/sources/default package/datasource-cfg.properties.

I'm using Netbeans 8.0 and I thought that I was accessing the datasource-cfg.properties in the Source Package. Sorry for not checking further and posting question directly.